# Issue when trying to sync multiple input with datalist id

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

I have a dynamic form with multiple input text. On some inputs I have datalists to sync them together : When I choose a value in 1 input, the others have the related value set.

This works perfectly when all the options in datalists are unique.. However, when I have multiple options with same value (but different Id), I don't get the right one... I get only the first option.

Here a snippet explaining my issue.

```js
$("#input1").on("change blur", function() {
 let id = $("#datalist1").find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").attr('id')
  if (id) {
    $("#input2").val($("#datalist2").find("#"+id).val())
    $("#idInput1").html(id)
    $("#idInput2").html('')
  }
})

$("#input2").on("change blur", function() {
 let id = $("#datalist2").find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").attr('id')
  if (id) {
    $("#input1").val($("#datalist1").find("#"+id).val())
    $("#idInput2").html(id)
    $("#idInput1").html('')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="datalist1" id="input1"/>
<datalist id="datalist1">
  <option id="1" value="Option1">Option1-1</option>
  <option id="2" value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option id="3" value="Option1">Option1-2</option>
</datalist>
<div id="idInput1"></div>

<input type="text" list="datalist2" id="input2"/>
<datalist id="datalist2">
  <option id="1" value="Test1">Test1</option>
  <option id="2" value="Test2">Test2</option>
  <option id="3" value="Test3">Test3</option>
</datalist>
<div id="idInput2"></div>
```

I can't use the option content to get the datalist Id (it will never be on the input)...

I can't use "select" instead of datalist... The users must be able to add informations

Does anyone have a solution or an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is `datalist` mandatory? This could be eventually done with `select` and a little trick

Comment: If it's possible with a `select` I'd like to. But I honestly don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datalist` doesn't support events
You can achieve the same result with dropdown and listening on a particular value being selected.

```
<select class="form-control bordered" id="dd_list">
    <option></option>
    <option value="val1" > Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2" > Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3" > Value 3</option>
    <option value="val4" > Value 4</option>
    <option value="val5" > Value 5</option>
    <option value='other'> Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="dd_list_other" class="form-control bordered" title="Press Escape to show DD" placeholder="Enter value or press ESC" style="display: none" />
```

And the JS code

```
$('#dd_list').on('change', function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    if( v == "other" ){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#dd_list_other').show();
        $('#dd_list_other').focus();
    }
});

$('#dd_list_other').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == 27){ // ESC keycode
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).hide();
        $('#dd_list').show();
    }
});
```

Check [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz1wu84d/)

Comment: That's a damn great answer ! With this I can use mostly all I want (Autocompletion, sync, ...)
Thank's for the trick !